# "displayof" in tkinter.font.Font.measure

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

The following `measure` method is defined in `class Font` of module `/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/font` or `import tkinter.font`:

```
def measure(self, text, displayof=None):
    "Return text width"
    args = (text,)
    if displayof:
        args = ('-displayof', displayof, text)
    return self._tk.getint(self._call("font", "measure", self.name, *args))
```

Questions:

1. What is`displayof`?
2. When and how do I use `displayof`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a widget as an argument. While rare, it’s possible to have multiple windows displaying on multiple displays with different pixel densities. If you have such a setup, this lets you decide which widget/display to use as the basis for determining the size of the string.

The default for this parameter is the root window.

Comment: Can you share an example script?

Comment: @SunBear: why do I need to do that? You can create an example script just as easily as I can.

Comment: If I have a Label A as a child of Window 1 displayed in Monitor 1 and Label B as a child of Window 2 displayed in Monitor 2, and I want to measure the text of Label A and B, are you saying `displayof` should be Label A and Label B, respectively, because you said it takes a widget as an argument? But here is also where I got confused. You also wrote it defaults to the root window. But a widget isn't a Window.

Comment: @SunBear: you can use any widget, it doesn't have to be the root window or an instance of `Toplevel`.